# Set Image and Text Side by Side in Table?

Tags: html

To begin with, I tried to text wrap it like any other picture, so I did but it just positions the picture underneath the text (not enough reputation to post pic). And my beginning code is just table width="1000" cellpadding="10" align="center" within the arrow brackets (yes- I do not know what they are called hah). It wasn't letting me type that at code like the rest, sorry! But anyways, what's the problem? What's a solution? I'm sure it's something simple! ![enter image description here][1]

```
    <td width="33%">
    Support the efforts of companies that are enrolled in the Non-GMO Project
 Verification
    <img src="bag.jpg" align="right" width="100" height="100"/>
    </td>
```

**I do not own Non-GMO Project. I am to recreate an organization website to the best of my ability with what I've learned in the semester**

Comment: In a table cell? Or in 2 different cells side by side?

Comment: If you want them in the same cell, use the style attribute `style='float:right|left'` per http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds4p6.html

Comment: Hm, I followed the website's guide and it still didn't adjust them. The picture stayed underneath. Is it possible I have something competing with this element that wouldn't allow it to do be aligned as I want?
And bytec0de, I have them in the same cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td width="33%">
<span style="float: left;">Support the efforts of companies that are enrolled in the Non-GMO Project Verification</span>
<img src="bag.jpg" style="float: right;" width="100" height="100"/>
</td>
```